# Laravel Unit Testing

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, lumen

I am implementing unit testing in laravel.
While running the test cases using the below command.

```
 vendor/bin/phpunit --filter = MethodName
```

It is prompting me to install composer,although I have already installed it.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you give the exact message you received?

Comment: You need to set up the project dependencies using Composer:
composer install
You can learn all about Composer on https://getcomposer.org/.

Comment: OK, that's not telling you you need to install *Composer*. That's telling you you need to *use* Composer to install *Laravel's dependencies*. Just type `composer install` (from the main folder of your Laravel install) and let it run.

Comment: Yes,I tried that too, but it's still giving the same error

Comment: Make sure the default phpunit.xml file is in your current working directory so phpunit can read it. The default one provided by laravel can also be found [in github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/phpunit.xml) and includes the `bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"` attribute which should remove that error.

Comment: No,it didn't solve the issue.Actually the thing is it's lumen so i am having different phpunit.xml structure.

Answer (score 0):

So finally I got the solution.
I deleted the entire vendor directory and then  `composer install`.
then `vendor/bin/phpunit --filter = MethodName` this worked.